# Issue in loading custom fonts in Android 4.2 (API 17)

Tags: android-webview

I have a static html file "myhtml.html" stored in my assets/html/ directory and this html loads custom font (stored under assets/fonts/) as follows:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'MyFont';
        src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf');
    }
</style>
```

I am loading this html using the following code:

```java
String html = getHtml(); // This method loads the myhtml.html from asset. This loads properly.
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webbox);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webSettings.setFixedFontFamily("fonts/myfont.ttf");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

This code works fine all the android versions except Android 4.2 (API 17).

In Android 4.2, the HTML is loaded but the custom font is not loaded.

Comment: In fact, this used to work on API 17. I suspect it was broken with the last patch update.

Comment: why don't you add this font in html file?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a bug. I filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54516

If anyone knows differently, please correct me. Also, if this bug bothers you, please star it to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

Please use(svg font). it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Changing

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

to

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://example.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

fixes the issue.